# Remove one or more dots at beginning of string

Tags: php, string

How can I remove the dot that starts a string?

```
$string = ". Hello world .";
```

I only want to remove the first dot, not the dot at the end.

Comment: sorry i did't tell you, i'm using php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple pattern would match any period (or sequence, since you suggested this) at the start of a string, or (following a request from the OP in the comments below) at the end of the string:

```
preg_replace( "/^\.+|\.+$/", "", "....Hello...." );
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/Nst5EX1k

Comment: I'm sorry to annoy you, but how can I Remove one or more dots at beginning and end of string ?

Answer (score 11):

```
ltrim('. Hello World! .','.');
```

Comment: much better answer than the regex ones

Answer (score 2):

Using `$stripped = trim($string, ' .');` is probably better and strips any space or dot.

Comment: it would be better to use "whitespace" maks along the dot, that is a default parameter in trim `trim($string, " .\t\n\r\0\x0B")`

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you're using PHP. Try:

```
$string = ". Hello World! .";
$pos = strrpos($string, ".");
$stripped = substr($string, $pos + 1);
```

Comment: Does this remove the "first" dot ?

Comment: It removes the first appearance of the dot character, wherever it is. To simply remove the first character, use `$stipped = substr($string, 1)` instead.

Comment: @H2CO3 i try it but the reuslt is empty, when i type >> echo $stripped; it's appear n'thing i modified it to <br/> $stripped = substr($string, ($pos * -1) - 1); <br/> then it worked good <br/> also this works >> $stipped = substr($string, 1);

but i want remove dottes from the first of string
i mean that i want each dot before characters be removed

are you understant me ?

Comment: if i have four dottes like $string = '...... Hello world ..';
<br/>
i want it to be $string = ' Hello world ..';
thanks very much

Comment: Awww you should really read the PHP stdlib docs, shouldn't you?

Comment: sorry i did't read it because i'm speaking arabic and i can't reading english well, sorry but what is the mean of stdlib ? ^^